# Is my understanding of this proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification

Given the definition:
A real number $x$ is said to be positive if $0\lt x$ and negative if $x\lt 0$, and the Axioms of order (Trichotomy, Transitivity, Monotonicity of addition and multiplication), prove that $0\lt 1$.

The approach that I have come across is as follows:
By the axiom of trichotomy, if $0$ is not less than $1$, then either $0=1$ or $1\lt 0$. But $0=1$ is false because the multiplicative identity axiom asserts that $0$ and $1$ are different numbers. If we assume that $1\lt 0$, then we form the following argument:

$1\lt 0$

$1+(-1)\lt 0+(-1)$

Since $1+(-1)=0$ and $0+(-1)=-1$, we have

$0\lt -1$ which by the definition above shows that $-1$ is positive. So,

$0(-1)\lt -1(-1)$

Since $0(-1)=0$ and $-1(-1)=1$, we have

$0\lt 1$

Here is where I am trying to understand how this proof works.
If $p$ is the statement, $1\lt 0$ and $q$ is the statement, $0\lt 1$, we have shown that $p$ implies $q$. However, by the axiom of trichotomy and the fact that $0=1$ is false, $p$ and $q$ have opposite truth values, and the only way the conditional of $p$ and $q$ can be true, having $p$ and $q$ not equal to each other, is for $p$ to be false and $q$ to be true. Hence, $1\lt 0$ is false, $0=1$ is false, and we have $0\lt 1$.

By the way, I have also seen the proof which uses the fact that all nonzero real numbers have positive squares to show that $1\gt 0$, but I am wondering if my explanation is correct.

Comment: Perfect!  You have it completely right.  Although you don't need a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You began your argument with the assumption that $1 < 0$.
Then you ended up with $0 < 1$, which contradicts trichotomy.
Hence your assumption is false.
Hence $1 \not< 0$.
Your remaining choices are $1 = 0$ and $1 > 0$.
We know $1 = 0$ is false.
so $1 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect.

But you don't need a proof by contradiction.

a) if x > 0, the -x < 0 and vice versa.

As you did with 1.  if x > 0 the 0 = -x + x > -x + 0 = -x.

b)x^2 >= 0.

x =0 => x^2 = 0.

if x > 0 then x^2 = x*x > x*0 = 0.

if x < 0 the -x > 0 and, by above, x^2 = (-x)^2 > 0.

c) 1 = 1^2 > 0.